# Add a custom button to an existing ribbon in Outlook 2010 and 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I want to customise the ribbon that is displayed when the "Home" tab is clicked in OUtlook 2010 and 2013.

Questions -

1. Is this possible? Or do I have to create a custom ribbon and cannot modify the existing ribbon?
2. If the existing ribbon can be modified, please can you'll direct me to links that can provide this information.

I absolutely have no clue where to start from with this. Any links, docs or samples will be helpful.
I've been going through msdn but it all speaks of custom ribbon and that doesn't fit my purpose. I need to modify the existing ribbon.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible... by creating a custom ribbon which will in turn be added to the Home tab.

First, create a custom ribbon. Here's an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692172.aspx#OfficeOLExtendingUI_Explorer

Then add:

```
idMso="TabMail"
```

to the **tab** tag on your XML. This will instruct Outlook to add your custom ribbon to Home tab.

Using the link's example, it would be like this:

```
<ribbon>
<tabs>
    <tab id="MyTab"
        idMso="TabMail"
        getVisible="MyTab_GetVisible"
        label="MyTab">
        <group label="MyGroup" id="MyGroup">
            <button id="MyButton"
                size="large"
                label="MyButton"
                imageMso="HappyFace"
                onAction="OnMyButtonClick"/>
        </group>
    </tab>
</tabs>
```

If you're using Visual Studio's designer instead of XML, set the **ControlId** property of your custom ribbon's tab to **TabMail**. Here's a walkthrough for custom ribbon creation with Visual Studio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386104(v=vs.100).aspx

And if you want to place your custom ribbon somewhere other than the Home tab, you'll need to find the locations's MSO ID. Microsoft provides a list which can be downloaded at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an existing ribbon can be modified. Follow the steps given below to customize an existing ribbon in Outlook 2010:

1. Open Outlook 2010.
2. Go to the top of the Ribbon and click the Office Button
   [image]
3. Click Outlook and then click on Options button.
4. In the left pane, select Customize Ribbon.
5. In the right pane, find the desired tab in the list of available tabs and expand it.
6. Use the list of available commands and the Add/Remove buttons to
   customize the tab.
7. Click the OK button and you will be done.